# FreeSWITCH: Wrong number of tries with originate_retries

Tags: freeswitch

[The documentation](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/originate_retries)  for originate_retries says

> Number of retries before giving up on originating a call (default is 0).

Because of this I would expect that:

- `originate_retries=0` = 1 call
- `originate_retries=1` = 2 calls (1 try and 1 retry)
- `originate_retries=2` = 3 calls (1 try and 2 retries)
- `originate_retries=3` = 4 calls (1 try and 3 retries)

But in my testing I get:

- `originate_retries=0` = 1 call
- `originate_retries=1` = 1 call
- `originate_retries=2` = 2 calls
- `originate_retries=3` = 3 calls

My originate command is:

```
originate{originate_timeout=5,originate_retries=<X>,originate_retry_sleep_ms=5000}user/662 &park()
```

And my FreeSWITCH version is:

```
FreeSWITCH Version 1.10.2-release-14-f7bdd3845a~64bit (-release-14-f7bdd3845a 64bit)
```

Am I doing something wrong here, do I understand the documentation wrong, or is the problem in freeswitch / the freeswitch documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Freeswitch source file *switch_ivr_originate.c* you can see implementation of this.

Variable `retries` is initialized with value of 1.

When you originate call it will check if value is greater than 0 and less than 101.

```
if ((var_val = switch_event_get_header(var_event, "originate_retries")) && 
    switch_true(var_val)) {
       int32_t tmp;
       tmp = atoi(var_val);
       /* allow large number of retries if timeout is set */
       if (tmp > 0 && (retry_timelimit_sec > 0 || tmp < 101)) {
           retries = tmp;
       } else {
           switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_SESSION_LOG(session), SWITCH_LOG_WARNING,
                      "Invalid originate_retries setting of %d ignored, value must be 
                       between 1 and 100\n", tmp);
    }
}
```

So if you set `originate_retries=0` it will actually be set to 1.

And at last, it will execute **originate** loop `retries` times.

```
for (try = 0; try < retries; try++) {
...
```